# Can Appium be used for web testing on a Mac with PyCharm?

Tags: automated-testing, python, appium, web-testing, mac

I wanted to automate my project, which has three parts:

1. Web testing
2. Ipad app
3. Ios App

I have started with the web testing, by following all the steps on appium.io and installed Appium Server, Appium-python-client, and pycharm professional.

I have created my first test but I was not able to run it. I tried importing

`from appium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilitites`

but it throws the error:

`Cannot find reference 'desired_capabilities' in '__init__.py'`

this is the base case i have

```py
import unittest
from typing import Dict

from appium import webdriver
from appium.options.common import AppiumOptions

desired_caps = {
    'platformName': 'Mac',
    'browserName': 'Chrome',
    'appium:automationName': 'XCUITest'
}

options = AppiumOptions()
# options.load_capabilities(desired_caps)

url = 'http://localhost:4723/wd/hub'
driver = webdriver.Remote(url, desired_caps)
driver.get("hhtps://www.google.com")

element = element.send_keys('admin')


driver.quit()
```

The code `driver = webdriver.Remote(url, desired_caps)` is asking for a `[str,bool]` value. How can I use `desired_capabilities` here?

Comment: Why do you need PyCharm Professional instead of free Community edition?

Answer (score 0):

Using automation strategy, If you are going to run tests in macOS or Windows in any browser, you can reuse your tests in pure selenium.

The web is already maintained in Selenium project. It’s the testing framework’s responsibility to combine those tools and others in one place

No Appium is required for the same and even Appium provides the dependencies to run the tests in mobile devices browsers also.

If you are using POM file while adding below Appium dependency to your POM while will make you to run your tests on iOS mobile devices browsers.

```
<appium.java.version>8.0.0</appium.java.version>
```